# I am trying to create my own module in python that performs actions using selenium but I am struggling with importing variables

Tags: python, selenium, import, scripting

Here's what I have so far:

My module is named myModule and I have subdirectories with **init**.py for each called 'actions' and 'xpaths' that I am importing.

```
from myModule import actions
```

in "actions" I have a function called siteLogin and I want to use variables from another portion of my module called xpaths:

```
from textLayer import xpaths
def siteLogin(webdriver, user, pass):
  webdriver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
  webdriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths.loginButtonXPath).click()
```

and lastly in textLayer I have xpaths:

```
loginButtonXPath = '//*[@id="button"]'
```

but when I try to run this code from commandline,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from myModule import actions
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
siteUser = 'myUsername'
sitePass = 'myPassword'
actions.siteLogin(driver, siteUser, sitePass)
```

I receive an error stating

> NameError: name 'loginButtonXPath' is not defined

and I tried importing xpaths from commandline as well but it didn't work. What does work is to enter the string without using a variable, but I would like to be able to use a variable so that it can be changed in the future.

Also entering

```
print(xpaths.loginButtonXPath)
```

works as intended to print the string if I import the 'xpaths' in the main code.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: Where are you calling the loginButtonXPath variable? I can only see xpaths.loginButton.

Comment: yeah, I just typed it wrong in the post but I have it correctly written in the code as xpaths.loginButtonXPath

Comment: have u tried saying `global loginButtonXPath` in the function where it is defined?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename each of your `init.py` files to `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when I remove the 'driver.get(...)' portion from within the function and call it individually, the rest seems to work. I'm not sure exactly why but I suppose that will be a different question to answer later on. For now, the solution is to isolate the clicking (and username and password entry, etc.) to its own function. Also, I imported the variables in the actual python commandline instead of inside the function 'actions' **init**.py but I'm not sure if that matters or not.